# .xls files suddenly won't open

Tags: ms-office

Since yesterday my .xls files will not open in Office for Mac 2011. They have always done so till then. I can still open .xlxs files. The default 'open with' option is still the Microsoft Excel.app. I haven't (not aware of) having made any software updates yesterday. The message I get is that the file c'cannot be accessed' because it 'may be read-only, or you may be trying to access a read-only location. Or, the server the document is stored on may not be responding'.

But, it is happening with ALL .xls files,whether on my own drive that I have no problem accessing for other files, on things just emailed to me, or as downloads from a Skydrive facility.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your main hard drive to something with only letters and optionally spaces.

That usually solves this issue with Microsoft's assumptions about characters in path names.